# Android split() works on Emulator but not on device

Tags: java, android, string, split

i´m currently facing a strange problem with the `str.split()` function. First off here´s my code:

```
     String[] seperated = content.split("<div id=\"results\" style=\"width: 175px; \">");
             Log.d("seperated length", "" + seperated.length);



             if(seperated.length>1){
                 Log.d("sep1 t2.", seperated[1]);

                 String[] sep2 = seperated[1].split("<div id=\"map\" ");

                 Log.d("sep2 t1", sep2[0]);

                 String[] sep3 = sep2[0].split("<div class=\"resultLine\">");
                 result = new String[sep3.length];
                 for(int i=1; i<sep3.length; i++){
                    String[] temp = sep3[i].split("class=\"icon1\">");
                    String[] temp2 = temp[1].split("<br>");
                    String[] temp3 = temp2[1].split("<br");
                    String[] temp4 = temp3[0].split("</a>");
                    result[i-1] = temp2[0] + " " +temp4[0];
                    Log.d("places", result[i-1]);


                 }
                 handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
             } else {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

             }
```

on the emulator the result Array is generated without problems but on the device the first split fails without an error or anything.
String content is the same as the one on the emulator.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails without an error or anything"? How do you know it failed if there is no error? What visible output is there? What did you expect to see? Does your program  continue to run or does it just hang? What do your logs say?

Comment: re-check your regular expression.

Comment: seperated.length equals 1 after the split (it should equal 2), therefore my app enters a loop and retrys to split the string. the only output are my log.d´s.

The expression does work in the emulator so it should work on the device as well shouldnt it?

Comment: whats is value of String 'content'?

Comment: the value of the String "content" is html code that i extract from a webview via a JS interface. Does the browser on the emulator have another UserAgent info? maybe thats my problem... i´ll go check it out Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StringUtils.split()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for splitting your Strings instead of the built-in String method. The fact that the String.split() argument is a regular expression (which needs correct escaping of special characters and the like), causes lots of errors.

You don't really want to mess with regular expressions there, you just want to have a string separated into tokens, right?